# Haskell - using Vector in a knapsack problem (optimization)

Tags: haskell

I was playing with a generalized knapsack problem (the size of the packs are random) and coded up :

```
import Data.Vector (generate, (!)) 

packed :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
packed a b c n 
  | n `mod` a == 0 || n `mod` b == 0 || n `mod` c == 0  = True
  | otherwise = packs!n where
    packs = generate' (n+1) go 
    go i =  (i == 0) || (i == a) || (i == b) || (i == c) || 
            (i > a && packs!(i `rem` a ) )  ||
            (i > b && packs!(i `rem` b ) )  ||
            (i > c && packs!(i `rem` c ) )  ||
            (i - a > 0 && packs!(i-a) ) || 
            (i - b > 0 && packs!(i-b) ) || 
            (i - c > 0 && packs!(i-c) ) 

generate' = Data.Vector.generate
```

But I was surprised that using Vector for access did little to nothing to speed up the code as I have seen it make significant changes in past code especially on large lists. Is there something wrong with the way it is being used in the above?

As a general question, if I call that twice, the second time doesn't remember the first time so it has to run through everything again, correct? I think since  a and b and c change, then it can't be memoized as well so are the better approaches than the above to deal with the calculation?

Ref :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: Yes, if you call `packed` twice, the vector will be recreated each time. How large are your `n`s? The speedup only becomes apparent for larger sizes. (Also note that `i - a > 0` is equivalent to `i > a`).

Comment: @PetrPudlák Large, 10**6-8

Comment: Then switching from list to vector should bring very significant improvement. Indexing lists is _O(n)_, and will be very slow for sizes like this. Maybe the bottleneck is elsewhere?